# Error 401 when trying to update status with twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, http-status-code-401

I am trying to update status on twitter using twitter4j. Everything works fine on localhost, but when I try to do it on server I get authorization error:

> 401:Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect.
>   {"error":"Invalid \/ used nonce","request":"\/1\/statuses\/update.json"}
>   TwitterException{exceptionCode=[15bb6564-00e4d61f], statusCode=401, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null, version=2.1.7-SNAPSHOT(build: 6498f401635aacf3388891cc5140b2086ff3f8aa)}

I generated access token for a user using "PIN" method on localhost. I think it shouldn't matter where it was generated, `accessToken.getToken()` and `accessToken.getTokenSecret()` values shouldn't depend on which machine I run them, they should work anywhere, right?

What does this error message mean? I don't understand "used nonce" part.

**UPDATE**

Ok something is really messed up somewhere. I am trying to generate access token on a server now and can't even make it to generate authorization URL for me:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer("twitterConsumerKey", "twitterConsumerSecret");

RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
System.out.println(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());
```

This fails with:

```
401:Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect.
Failed to validate oauth signature and token
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[68a00bf1-d29b9452], statusCode=401, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null, version=2.1.7-SNAPSHOT(build: 6498f401635aacf3388891cc5140b2086ff3f8aa)}
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:308)
        at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:72)
        at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:103)
        at twitter4j.http.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:124)
        at twitter4j.TwitterOAuthSupportBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterOAuthSupportBaseImpl.java:87)
        at twitter4j.Twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(Twitter.java:54)
        at twitter4j.TwitterOAuthSupportBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterOAuthSupportBaseImpl.java:80)
        at twitter4j.Twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(Twitter.java:54)
```

On localhost everything works fine.

Comment: Deprecated, new people coming across this thread: try this new OAuth Tutorial: http://goo.gl/99vpL

Comment: The comment above is wrong. This question is still fully valid and the OAuth Tutorial advertised in the comment above has nothing to do with the question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A week and few grey hairs later it turned out that the problem was in local time on a server which was off. Someone did a great job with clear error messages on Twitter.

Comment: i have same error.Could you please explain what to do to come out of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A nonce is a value that is designed to only be used once.

My guess is that the code you are using to generate a nonce is saving the nonce and trying to reuse it.

I am not familiar with the twitter4j library, but I would check and make sure you are generating a new nonce for each request.

Answer (score 0):

For your "401:Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect" error. Make sure you also include the verifier pin with the request as part of the signature base.